# Организация совместного перевода на время отсутствия активных корректоров

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Уже какое-то (*относительно продолжительное*) время у нас встали все вопросы по локализации сайта.

Так получилось, что на данный момент у нас неактивен ни один из корректоров переводов
А их, насколько я понимаю, у нас было три:

- αλεχολυτ
- VladD
- Nick Volynkin

αλεχολυτ долгое время самостоятельно проделывал огромную работу по переводу ресурса.
Откровенно говоря мы просто перекладывали ответственность за переводы на одного человека, что с нашей стороны было безответственно и несправедливо по отношению к нему.

Я и сам многократно создавал вопросы про отсутствие перевода в том или ином разделе нашего сайта. И я всегда знал, что придёт Алекс и всё сделает. И так поступал не только я. Так делали практически все. Все принимали это как должное, выражая безусловную благодарность за вклад, но не задумываясь о том, что стоило это самому пользователю.

Поэтому когда у участника, который уже и так внес неоценимый вклад в наше сообщество, не хватает сил и ресурсов, чтобы поддерживать активность на прежнем уровне нам нужно не сидеть и ждать сложа руки его возвращения, а подхватить знамя и нести дальше, продолжая поддержку работы нашего ресурса.

И осознав это я засучил рукова, зарегистрировался на traducir и стал добавлять переводы, но столкнулся с проблемой:

На время получения прав корректора Алекс себя уже хорошо зарекоммендовал при наличии двух активных корректоров (Влада и Ника). После получения прав корректора, Алекс смог сам добавлять и сам утверждать свои правки. В текущей же ситуации у нас нет ни одного корректора и нет зарекомендовавших себя переводчиков. И никто больше из участников сообщества не может добавить и утвердить перевод "в одно лицо".

И нам предстоит делать это коллегиально.
Я согласен добавлять переводы в traducir, но, согласно правилам, я не могу довести их до публикации самостоятельно.

Поэтому нам придётся сформировать небольшую инициативную группу и предложить сценарий для совместной работы.

Comment: Я где-то рядом. Не всё потеряно :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, любимый ты наш человек! :-) Это здорово :-) Но все равно, лучше мы тебе жизнь чуть упростим :-)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо! метки с обработанных вопросов уберу чтобы не мешали.

Comment: тестирование кажется прошло успешно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Дисклеймер:
> Сейчас чуть получше разобрался с тем, как работают переводы, поэтому часть вопросов и заблуждений в предыдущей версии сценария отпала сама собой.

Обычный сценарий работы выглядит следующим образом:

- Участник обнаруживает на сайте непереведенный текст и создает вопрос на мете с мектой `локализация`
- Участники в ответах предлагают перевод
- После чего кто-то из участников добавляет предложение перевода в traducir
- После Reviewer подтверждает или отклоеяет предложение и оно через пару дней идет в публикацию.

И я во всем этом вижу несколько проблем:

- Насколько я заметил, у нас не так чтобы много активных переводчиков в traducir
- traducir и мета два отдельных ресурса, связанных между собой только семантически
- на мете крайне сложно понять и отслеживать на каком именно этапе находится тот или иной вопрос
- на мете крайне сложно найти какие именно переводы сейчас нуждаются в подтверждении
- также сложно в системе traducir понять, какие именно переводы сейчас горячо обсуждаются и что именно нужно переводить и подтверждать в первую очередь.

Для организации всего этого я предлагаю пару вещей:

#### Первое

Для того чтобы reviewer мог быстро оценить и сразу подтвердить перевод в traducir необходимо придерживаться определенного формата сообщений, чем можно упростить ему жизнь reviewer'у и убрать лишний этап поиска нужного сообщения в системе traducir.

Ничего сверхестественного делать не нужно, просто в ответах при добавлении предложений нужно сразу указывать:

- оригинальное сообщение
- перевод
- ссылку на сообщение в системе traducir

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

> Stellar Answer
> Звездный ответ
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18081

#### Второе

Предлагаю ввести новую метку `подтверждение-перевода`, чтобы можно было сразу понять на каком этапе находится вопрос и чтобы на мете можно было отфильтровать переводы, которые нуждаются в подтверждении.

#### Итог

При соблюдении этих двух, казалось бы незначительных, и простых  правил можно будет упростить процесс принятия правок и доведения переводов до публикации.

1. Добавление вопроса на мету с меткой `локализация`
2. Добавление предложений по переводу в ответах

   2.1 Добавление перевода в traducir с указанием ссылки на предложение в ответе

   2.2 Добавление метки `подтверждение-перевода`
3. Отфильтровав вопросы по метке `подтверждение-перевода`, желающие могут принять переводы, перейдя по ссылкам, указанным в ответах
4. После подтверждения перевода, снимаем метку `подтверждение-перевода` и закрываем вопрос

---

В ближайшее время я пройдусь по открытым вопросам по локализации и добавлю свои предложения перевода в traducir.

Поэтому, если у кого-то возникло желание помочь мне с подтверждением переводов: 
go, я создал ([подтверждение-перевода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0))

---

**PS1:** Да и если, αλεχολυτ найдёт минуту-другую: ему будет проще пройтись по данной метке и подтвердить понравившиеся переводы.

---

**PS2:** Насколько я понял, Qwertiy, также может утверждать переводы в traducir, поэтому ему данный механизм также будет в помощь ибо всегда можно будет найти вопросы, на которые уже подготовили переводы, которые ждут его одобрения.

---

**PS3:** Принимать переводы имеют право следующие пользователи:

- g3rv4 ♦
- Aer
- Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦
- Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica ♦
- αλεχολυτ
- JNat ♦
- Qwertiy ♦
- PashaPash ♦

Из данного списка участниками непосредственно нашего сообщества являются:
Nicolas, Suvitruf, αλεχολυτ, Qwertiy, PashaPash

Из них активен только Qwertiy.
Может добавить его кого-то в данный список?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно ли ссылку на каждую строку добавлять на мету? На Traducir есть кнопка Mark as urgent, можно ею помечать те строки, которые нуждаются в переводе. Кроме того, можно просто снести бесполезные предложения, которые висят уже несколько лет (неиспользуемые строки для Teams). Тогда в списке новых предложений не будет ничего лишнего, и проверяющий может пройтись по нему; достаточно кинуть клич "есть неутвержденные строки, посмотрите". Есть и уведомления о новых предложениях и новых строках, но я не знаю, работают ли они.

В идеале неплохо бы добиться, чтобы бесполезных строк в базе вообще не было, либо их можно было как-то отфильтровать. Если Teams не локализован, загрузка строк для него в Transifex и Traducir это просто лишняя работа для всех, и лишний сетевой трафик когда все это обновляется.

Comment: Удалить лишнее - как мне кажется несбыточная мечта. Если даже это возможно, то это требует большого вклада со стороны ревьюверов и модераторов. А данный пост отчаяния, возник как раз по причине отсутствия у них времени и возможностей.

Comment: Относительно `Mark as urgent` - как по мне так всех проблем он не решает. Но тут не мне судить. Я сейчас потихоньку подготавливаю следующую пачку предложений и на ней протестируем вашу гипотезу. Если так будет удобнее ревьюверу - то так и поступим

Comment: В любом случае - спасибо за обратную связь.

Comment: Кстати, мне в какой-то момент ( полгода назад) показалось что Ваш профиль пропал. Я плохо искал или Вас можно поздравить с возвращением?)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Там сейчас 14 ожидающих предложений, из них кажется только одно новое (от вас), остальные висят давно и либо к неиспользуемым строкам, либо некорректны. Не так уж много работы их отклонить. Но да, лучше спросить у активных ревьюверов, как им удобнее.

Comment: Не удалял профиль, но долго неактивен, это да.